# Version of setsockopt

Tags: c#, setsockopt

I need to use the following method to define the receive buffer for specific sockets. But the given one is compatible for C++ , so please kindly advise me the C# version of the method.

```
(void)setsockopt(m_serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&m_recvBufferSize), sizeof(m_recvBufferSize));
```

Comment: `Socket.SetSocketOption()` ?

Comment: To set receive buffer size,  System.Net.Socket.ReceiveBufferSize can be used. Compatible api for Berkeley sockets setsockopt is Socket.SetSocketOption(), already proposed

Comment: Thanks. it works for me.